# perl array issue in using strings as array elements

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the below code.  I am trying to find a match of 3 words in my log file and print the line if the match is found (only if all 3 words are present). It works fine if I hardcode the words (`@typedefs`) , but its not working if I have the same words in  a array with strings (`@typedefs_new`). What is the mistake I am doing ?

```
my $str1="laa";
my $str2="faa";
my $str3="baa";

my @typedefs = qw(laa,faa,baa);
my @typedefs_new = ($str1,$str2,$str3);

my $file="/pathtofile/logfile.log";
open (FILE, $file) or die $!;

print "Output using typdefs_new array\n";
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
if ( any { $line =~ /$_/ } @typedefs_new ) {
    print $line;
  }
}

 print "Output using typdefs array\n";
while ( my $line = <FILE> ) {
if ( any { $line =~ /$_/ } @typedefs ) {
    print $line;
  }
}
```

logfile.log:

```
laa ferg gerg faa rgrebf baa abc def
fber rgreg rgre greg bgbg rghgr grhr
```

Output:

```
 Output using typedefs_new array
 laa ferg gerg faa rgrebf baa abc def
 fber rgreg rgre greg bgbg rghgr grhr

 Output using typedefs array
 laa ferg gerg faa rgrebf baa abc def
```

Comment: [choroba pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28050781/176646) why you're getting different results for your different arrays, but I'll add that if you want to only match lines that include all three keywords, you should be using `all`, not `any`. You should also change your regex to something like `/\b$_\b/` to avoid matching words like `blaa` and `faaa`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`qw()` separates words by whitespace, not by comma. So, your code is equivalent to

```
my @typedefs = ( 'laa,faa,baa' );
```

[warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) should have told you:

```
Possible attempt to separate words with commas
```

Comment: if that were the code they are actually using though, they wouldn't have got the output they say